# MSVC conditional breakpoint defined by calling function

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Assume that I wanted to debug the following simple program. And that I want to define a breakpoint in the function `bar()`.

```
#include <iostream>

void bar() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

void foo() {
    bar();
}

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    bar();
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

As a function might be called a lot of times in a real world example, I only wanted the debugger to stop if `bar()` was called inside `foo()`. So that the debugger will stop only once in the given example.

It should look like `CALLER_FUNCTION=foo()`, where `foo()` should be found somewhere in the stack backtrace.

Is it possible in MSVC2010 to define a conditional breakpoint that has this specific behavior?